# How does one format the public key for use in the jwt.io debugger?

Tags: jwt

I am trying to validate how one uses the nifty debugger at [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) to validate a JWT but I cannot find out how to format the public key so that it works in that "debugger".

Answer (score 0):

The answer turns out to be the PEM format of the key--specifically the text between

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
```

and

```
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

inclusive.  Transforming into the PEM format can be done using Java's `keytool` along with the `openssl` tool.  The details of the transformation can be found elsewhere.